# how to add pause and cancel action downloading one file by using NSURLSessionDataTask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pause, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am using this approach for downloading any file from the given URL. I want to add pause and resume functionality while downloading.

```
 - (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {

if (self.downloadTask){
    [self.downloadTask cancel];
    self.downloadTask=nil;


     self.progressView.progress=0.0f;


     }

 }




- (IBAction)pauseButtton:(id)sender {



    if (self.downloadTask){

        [self.downloadTask suspend];

    }

}
```

But these code is not working!!

Comment: Any context? It should work. Is the download task nil?

Comment: when i give resume ....[self.downloadTask resume];
downloading starting from 1st.

Comment: As the document said: `A task, while suspended, produces no network traffic and is not subject to timeouts. A download task can continue transferring data at a later time. All other tasks must start over when resumed`. How is your downloadTask declared?

Comment: my download task NSURLSessionDataTask

Comment: So you have to use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` in order to achieve your pause function.

Comment: actually my url in  NSMutableURLRequest how i do it with NSURLSessionDownloadTask by using NSMutableURLRequest.?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`NSURLSessionDownloadTask`](http://NSURLSessionDownloadTask) cancel the download with `-cancelByProducingResumeData:` and resume it with `-downloadTaskWithResumeData:` or `-downloadTaskWithResumeData:completionHandler:`.

Comment: i am using NSURLSessionDataTask for downloading

Comment: Why? This seems to be the root of the problem.